# Attach link to 3d-force-graph node

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

Is there a way to attach a link to the nodes in 3d-force-graph (https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) so that if a user clicks on a node they are taken away to a specific (or customised) url?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found in the `.onNodeClick` function. For example, add a link to your json:

```
'nodes': [
    {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "<h2>Title 1</h2>",
    "val": 1,
    'link': 'test.html?id=1',
    },
```

And add the following to your graph object:

```
.onNodeClick(function(node){
    window.location.href = node.link;
})
```